# What is maximum length of an AWS AMI name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, aws-sdk, amazon-ami

Is there any limit on length of the AWS AMI name(the immutable name) that would be given by AWS upon creation of an AMI? I don't find it anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

AMI names must be between 3 and 128 characters long.

Further, if you are looking for characters, you can include letters, numbers, `(`, `)`, `.`, `-`, `/` and `_`

Here's the source as requested.

[image]

Comment: A source would be helpful.

Comment: The source would be AWS itself. Edited the answer

Comment: It would be nice if they'd provide documentation for this instead of forcing us to discover it on our own through intentional failures!

Comment: I agree, couldn't find any aws docs for this. Guess they want us to learn it in the hard way

Answer (score 0):

The help bubble on the **Image name** field in the Amazon EC2 management console says:

> Description of the image. This field is limited to 127 characters in length and cannot be modified.